# How to detect which scrolling child of NestedScrollView was scrolled?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a parent NestedScrollView that contains 2 recycler views. One scrolls horizontally and the other one scrolls vertically. How can I detect which one was scrolled? Below is my xml layout.

I can't extract my recyclerviews from NestedScrollView because this nested scroll view is being used inside a coordinator layout so I must keep my recyclerviews inside the NestedScrollview.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContent"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <TextView
            style="@style/GatewayLabel"
            android:id="@+id/privateGatewaysLabel"
            android:text="@string/private_gateways_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/privateGatewaysRecycler"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privateGatewaysLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sharedGatewayLabel"
            style="@style/GatewayLabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/shared_gateways_label"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privateGatewaysRecycler" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sharedGatewaysRecycler"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sharedGatewayLabel" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check by adding this observer to ur nested scrollview object  then you can act upon

```html
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                if (yourViews.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {  //ditect if your views visibilty is in bound or not the
                    
                } else {
                  
                }

            }
        });
```

For your Recyclerviews scroll smoothness, you can use

```html
 YourRecylerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```